# how to set imageview's height and width using onTouch in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using below code to set an imageview's width. but it is not working.

xml:

`

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/card1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/slot"
        android:src="@drawable/spade_3" />`
```

and java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play__computer);
    card1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card1);
    card2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.card2);           
    card1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    card2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
}
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{

     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
             v.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
             return true;
         } else{
             return false;
         }

     }
}
```

when i touch the image view, it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
param.width=200;
v.setLayoutParams(param);
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: @arjunkn... how can i set default position when i click that imageview again? i used if() but no use..

Comment: store the old value to a variable and set layoutParam when click next time.

a=param.width;

after next click

param.width=a;
then v.setLayoutParams(param);

i guess it works.

Comment: but in your answer how can i find the next click.

Comment: @nick just add a boolean variable as false. In it just make it true at first click. and check if its true and if false do the first width change and make it true and if its true then its the next click do vice versa.
like 
if(isClicked==false){
//do the first change
}else{
//do the next change
}

got the point. actually iam done things in this way don't know its the correct but worked for me.

Comment: boolean isClicked=false;    //declare as global
a=param.width;
the inside your ontouch
if(isClicked==false){
isClicked=true;
param.width=200;
v.setLayoutParam(param);
}else{
param.width=a;
v.setLayoutParam(param);
isClicked=false;
}

check the code and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{

     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
             ImageView imgView = (ImageView) v;

             int width = 100;
             int height = 100;

             LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
             imgView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

             return true;
         } else{
             return false;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutParams to set the height and width:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout( this );
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

You can access any LayoutParams from code using View.getLayoutParams

Comment: thanks for answering anchit. how can i use this in RelativeLayout?